# How can I show multiple entry types in the same page

Tags: entry, entry-type

I have two entry types in a same structure, I want to get some values from these two types in a same page. Is it possible?

I tried:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('businessProfile').type(['type1','type2]) %}
```

And the `entry.type` still shows only one type. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can fetch all entry type when you just leave don't include `.types`. Besides that your command is missing an `'` otherwise it is totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

And just to make sure: you are iterating over the results, right? because it actually should be:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('businessProfile').type(['type1','type2]).all() %}
{% for entry in entries %} ...
... Here {{entry.type}} should be different
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Sorry man, it doesn't work. It's like only one entry type can be reached at one time. Because when I change the type and save it, the type will be shown. And when I switch to the other type and save, the result change to that type.

Comment: But you have more entries in your section than one don't you?

Comment: @RobinSchambach Yes, I have two entries under the section.

Comment: @yuxia do you expect to get both types in the `entry.type` function? Because it will only return you the current selected type

Comment: @RobinSchambach Yeah, I wanna get some values from both entry types at the same time. But now it's like impossible

Comment: What do you mean by "get some values?" you can access all available types in your section by `entry.getSection().getEntryTypes()` but this has actually nothing to do with your entry and should not be done in a loop